# Endevor Load modules - Identify source code versions

Tags: git, github, gitlab, endevor

We are looking to migrate source codes from Endevor to a git-based system like Github , Gitlab or bitbucket and store the load modules in artifactory.
In Endevor - We can get the source code version of a particular load module. How can we achieve this in Github combined with artifactory?